# Encryption and Decryption of File

Tags: encryption, des

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a file. The file can be any file like txt, jpg, doc, pdf.
The IV is prepended to the cipher text. but while decrypting if i read first 8 bytes it gives me different value then the value of IV while encryption.

Here is my code to encrypt the file

```
fsOut = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                des.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretkey);                 

                des.GenerateIV();                

                desencrypt = des.CreateEncryptor();
                cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsOut, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                //write the IV to beginning of encrypted data
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(cryptoStream);
                bw.Write(des.IV, 0, des.IV.Length);

                // Now will initialize a buffer and will be 
                // processing the input file in chunks. 
                // This is done to avoid reading the whole file (which can be
                // huge) into memory. 
                int bufferLen = 4096;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                int bytesRead;
                do
                {
                    // read a chunk of data from the input file 
                    bytesRead = filestream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
                    // Encrypt it 
                    cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                while (bytesRead != 0);

                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
```

This produces an encrypted file to the specified location.

Now below is my decryption code

```
des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                des.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretkey);

                byte[] iv = new byte[8];
                sourcefile.Read(iv, 0, 8);
                des.IV = iv;

                desdecrypt = des.CreateDecryptor();
                msOut = new MemoryStream();
                cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(sourcefile, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

                StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter("D:\\tempDecrypted.jpg");
                fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptoStream).ReadToEnd());
                fsDecrypted.Flush();
                fsDecrypted.Close();
```

Comment: You need to write the IV to the unencrypted stream.

Comment: Some more notes: 1) DES isn't secure. Use AES instead. 2) You shouldn't use ASCII for a proper key. Either it's a proper key, then you need to use hex or Base64. Or it's a password, then you need to use a salted password hash to turn it into a key.

Comment: well, i am totally new to this and confused which is best and how to implement. basically i want to encrypt & decrypt files rather than string data

Comment: @CodesInChaos - can you please show me how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your IV to the `CryptoStream` so it will be transformed to ciphertext. The IV should be prepended to the ciphertext in plain, it should not be part of the ciphertext.

Comment: ya but how to do that. I mean how to write the IV as plain text to the beginning of my cipher text

Comment: by writing it to `fsOut` maybe? Sheesh.